# Greedy Binary Search C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I’m trying to solve the problem https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO12002

**Problem**

Given integer arrays V, W and array of pairs C (start, end). You have to find i, j such that W[j] - V[i] is minimum and at least one of the pairs should lie within V[i] and W[j]

**Algorithm**

- Sort W and Contests according to start time.
- For each V[i] in V, Binary search to find Contest with Start time >= V[i], let the found contest be at index c (small c)
- Find W[i] in W such that it is the first element >= Contest[c].end_time, let it be j.
- t2 = W[j], t1 = W[i], then ans = min(ans, t2 - t1 + 1)

However, although the logic sounds good to me and 3/4th of the test cases, this doesn't seem to pass the other test cases.

Here's my code

```
int i;
// Input
cin >> n >> x >> y;

V = new int[x];
W = new int[y];
C = new pair<int, int>[n];

for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    cin >> C[i].first >> C[i].second;

for (i = 0;i < x;i++)
    cin >> V[i];

for (i = 0;i < y;i++)
    cin >> W[i];

// End Input

sort(W, W + y);
sort(C, C + n);

int ans = INT_MAX, c, t1, t2, j; 
for (i = 0;i < x;i++)
{
    t1 = V[i];
    // gr_eq is equivalent to std::lower_bound for pair<int, int>
    // Def: gr_eq(pair<int,int>,low,high,target)
    c = gr_eq(C, 0, n - 1, t1); 
    // he will attend the cth contest
    if (c >= 0)
    {
        j = gr_eq(W, 0, y - 1, C[c].second); // lower_bound for integer array
        if (j >= 0)
        {
            t2 = W[j];
            ans = min(ans, t2 - t1 + 1);
        }
    }
}

/* output */
cout << ans << endl;

// Free memory
delete [] V;
delete [] W;
delete [] C;
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there an implementation or logical error?

**Edit**
Here is my implementation of gr_eq

```
//
// Find number >= targer
//
int gr_eq(pair<int, int> * a, int low, int high, int target)
{
    int mid;
    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (a[mid].first >= target)
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }

    if ( a[low].first >= target)
        return low;
    else
        return -1;
}

int gr_eq(int * a, int low, int high, int target)
{
    int mid;
    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (a[mid] >= target)
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }

    if ( a[low] >= target)
        return low;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong ? Is there an implementation or logical error?

Comment: You need to debug. Find an example input that fails. Step through the code. See if things work like expected. Discover if they don't.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: I can't find any counter examples to my logic mentioned above, which works for every test case I think of, and as is the policy, test data is secret.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say exactly on what cases your code fails, neither do you detail the exact definition of your gr_eq.
However, if it does use (or exactly mimics) lower_bound(), then its search range is [first, last) rather than [first, last] or, in other words, from first, included, to last, *not included*. In your case, the last elements (n-1 and y-1) will not be included in the provided range.